# Paginate entries by arbitrary cycle in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate, kaminari

I have a model:

entry (created_at: datetime, temperature: float, melt_type: string)

I need to paginate entries by cycle (rather than a set number of entries).

A cycle is defined by the **first** entry with any melt_type value to the last entry *before* another melt_type is entered. (melt_type appears for a few days at the *beginning* of a cycle lasting ~40 days, but won't appear any other time in a cycle).

I've found a few pagination gems (will_paginate or Kaminari), but am having difficulty finding a solution that doesn't use an exact number of entries per page.

Comment: Do you want to set the entries per page using `will_paginate`?

Comment: Not necessarily. It just seemed well supported, but I could go with a different solution.

Comment: kaminari seems closer to what I need
https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/Kaminari-recipes#-how-do-i-paginate-an-array

Comment: Is melt_type unique between cycles? Or it may return later?

Comment: melt_type indicates the beginning of a new cycle. 

melt_type entries will occur for the first ~8 days per cycle, but not in the middle of cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking of this the wrong way.

What I really needed was to create a single table inheritance in which I created a new model called melt_cycle that inherits from entries instead of the ActiveRecord::Base.

It does require the user to designate the beginning of the melt_cycle, but that's not unreasonable.

Now I just need to figure out how to automatically assign entries to ID of the previous melt_cycle_start

Now my entry model looks like
(created_at: datetime, temperature: float, melt_type: string, melt_cycle_start: boolean)

Here's a great tutorial from Team Treehouse on Single Table Inheritance:
http://teamtreehouse.com/library/rails-models/migrations-and-relationships/single-table-inheritance